# how to make gif file with video file in flutter

Tags: flutter, makefile, gif

i'm trying to make gif with video file.

just one - two seconds gif like Tiktok thumnail

but I don't know how to do it

I tryed many things but didn't make it

Image Package

https://pub.dev/packages/image

Variable FPS for animated GIF encoding.

It might be the solution but I can't find any example of it

How Can I make this? anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Use **video_trimmer** https://pub.dev/packages/video_trimmer instead

```
// Example of defining a custom command

// This is already used for creating GIF by
// default, so you do not need to use this.

await _trimmer
    .saveTrimmedVideo(
        startValue: _startValue,
        endValue: _endValue,
        ffmpegCommand:
            '-vf "fps=10,scale=480:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0',
        customVideoFormat: '.gif')
    .then((value) {
  setState(() {
    _value = value;
  });
});
```

---

**OUTDATED:**

flutter_video_compress is an older package, but should work for most situations. Sometimes the file path can be an issue depending on which file picker you choose for `videoFile.path`

**Convert video to a gif**

```
final file = await _flutterVideoCompress.convertVideoToGif(
  videoFile.path,
  startTime: 0, // default(0)
  duration: 2, // default(-1)
  // endTime: -1 // default(-1)
);
debugPrint(file.path);
```

**Can be found here:**

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_compress